# Issue with simple 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

In my .htaccess file I have the following redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /concrete5-themes/street/ http://www.c5themes.co.uk/street-theme-for-concrete5/
```

However, this sends you to `http://www.c5themes.co.ukstreet` which is obviously wrong.

What's wrong?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Its the same in another browser.  The only other rule I have is:

Redirect 301 /concrete5-themes/ http://www.c5themes.co.uk

This works fine.  I am using Concrete5 CMS which also has some different rules further down:

# -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try at the top of your *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?c5themes\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^concrete5-themes/street(.*) http://www.c5themes.co.uk/street-theme-for-concrete5/ [R=301,L]
```

Example inputs:

> http://www.example.co.uk/concrete5-themes/street/1/1
> http://www.example.co.uk/concrete5-themes/street

Redirect:

> http://www.c5themes.co.uk/street-theme-for-concrete5/

---

You can experiment here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: That works very nicely, thanks very much :)  I have a load more rules which I can now add from your "template" too.